# How do I create/edit a PNG file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, png

I've written a program that can create digital art. Images like the Mandelbrot Set and the Julia Set. But I'm looking to save these images as PNGs. At present, in Java, I'm generating the images in an application window and then taking a screen shot of the display. However, I lose the finer detail of these images. Plus, this method also reduces the physical size of the images as well. I want to potentially be able to make a big poster out of these pictures.

In C#, I'm using the following:
`Bitmap myimage = new Bitmap("image.png");` and: `myimage.SetPixel(x,y, Color.FromArgb(255*colors[x,y], 255*colors[x,y], 255*colors[x,y]);` where `colors[,]` is some value between 0 and 1.

The code runs fine, minus the Bitmap declaration. My understanding is that `new Bitmap(filepath);` allows you to edit and manipulate the PNG image. Am I right to think that? How do I create/edit a PNG file in C#?

(edit)PS: The PNG file, "image.png", does exist in the solution folder.

Comment: *"Am I right to think that?"* - Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to know the step by step process in creating the PNG file.

- Setup Aspose.Imaging for .NET package from Nuget.org.
- Include reference to following two namespaces: Aspose.Imaging,
  Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.
- Specify license using SetLicense method before converting.
- Read BMP file into an Image object.
- Set attributes  for output PNG image using PngOptions class.
- Save the output PNG image with the specified PNG options.

Code to create PNG image from BMP

```
using System;
//Use following namespaces to create PNG image
using Aspose.Imaging;
using Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions;

namespace CreatePNGImage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Set license before creating PNG image from BMP
            Aspose.Imaging.License AsposeImagingLicense = new Aspose.Imaging.License();
            AsposeImagingLicense.SetLicense(@"c:\asposelicense\license.lic");

            //load input BMP image 
            Image BmpToPngImage = Image.Load("InputBMPImage.bmp");
            
            //set attributes of the output PNG file
            PngOptions PNGImageOptions = new PngOptions();
            PNGImageOptions.ResolutionSettings = new ResolutionSetting(300, 300);
            PNGImageOptions.CompressionLevel = 6;

            //save converted output PNG image
            BmpToPngImage.Save("OutputPNGImage.png", PNGImageOptions);

        }
    }
}
```

Try this to create the PNG file out of c#.